# Adding Editor into a component

Tags: joomla, editor, components

My task is to get/make WYSIWYG editor. I read that u can get it quite simple:

```
$editor = JFactory::getEditor();
            $params = array( 'smilies'=> '1' ,
                             'style'  => '1' ,  
                             'layer'  => '1' , 
                             'table'  => '1' ,
                             'clear_entities'=>'1'
                             );
            echo $editor->display( 'desc', '', '400', '400', '20', '20', false, null, null, null, $params);
```

Problem is,

1. How can I remove the buttons I don't want to see?
2. How can I place it (for example in second field when I've 4 of them?)

Right now, all that code is view.example.php file.

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla form fields you can easily set this parameters
To remove smilies and table button

Check this https://docs.joomla.org/Editor_form_field_type.

To achieve the same in legacy way you can do as explained here https://docs.joomla.org/API16:JEditor/display (J16 API)

Its quite simple. If you go through this code

```
 $params = array( 'smilies'=> '1' ,
                             'style'  => '1' ,  
                             'layer'  => '1' , 
                             'table'  => '1' ,
                             'clear_entities'=>'1'
                             ); //You are enabling with '1'
```

What you are trying to do is enabling `smilies, style, layer, table and clear_entities`. If you want to disable any of these simply change 1 to 0. so 'table' => '0' will remove table button.

If you are using Tinymce editor then you have the option to enable disable buttons in the extended mode.

You can even authorise buttons for different users at different levels.

You need to find the Plugin Editor - TinyMCE. Enable the extended mode and on the Advanced tab you can play with buttons.

Check this image

[image]

Comment: Changed every parameter to 0 and nothing changed. Editor has same functions ect. I wanted to remove hyper link options ect.

Also about - https://docs.joomla.org/Editor_form_field_type. I can't get to xml file anymore (as my component has been added), do I've to install component again with new additions?

Comment: @Poo123 Please check the edited answer. This may help.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Is it also possible to hide that button "Turn on/off editor" (below the editor itself) and just make it default "on"? If so, then how?

Comment: Yes its poosible to hide it by adding this to your css file `.toggle-editor {
    display: none;
}`

Comment: and how is it possible to always turn it ON (so it doesn't show "Turn on/off you editor"?)